# Error in if (by == 0 && del == 0) return(from) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, plotrix

I am new to R. [I have a dataframe qtr_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p3Uf.png)

I am trying to draw a 3D pie chart for the same using the code

```
qtr_1 <- sqldf::sqldf('Select Tier, Sales2016 from final_table where Quarter = 1')
qtr_1 <- qtr_1 %>% group_by(Tier) %>% summarise(sales_2016 = sum(Sales2016))
qtr_1 <- pie3D(qtr_1$sales_2016,labels = qtr_1$Tier, explode=0.1, col=rainbow(length(qtr_1$Tier)),
                 main="Qtr 1")
```

I get the error:

> Error in if (by == 0 && del == 0) return(from) :    missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed

is.na(qtr_1) gives false for all.

If some help me out with this please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't make a 3D pie chart.

Comment: @Dason when I try pie(qtr_1) I get Error in pie(qtr_1) : 'x' values must be positive.

Comment: What happens if you drop the 'out' group. But also... please don't make a 3D pie chart.

Comment: I just require a simple pie chart for that data, so since you since I am going without the pie 3D chart. @Dason

Comment: Hello, @Dason appreciate your time and patience. Well, the Tier was a factor and earlier I tried to change it to a character and draw a pie but I failed but this time it worked. So I am good and it is all up and running. Have a great day ahead.